# How to update specific row in Sqlalchemy ORM for a non unique primary key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Am attempting to use SQLAlchemy ORM to update a particular row in the database but because I want to keep history of everything that has ever happened to the row I want to version off the record and keep the same primary key i.e. the primary key isn't unique. So when I try to version off the old record and create a new record I get the following error"

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError: UPDATE statement on table 'category' expected to update 1 row(s); 2 were matched.
```

trying to use the following function:

```
def update_category(db: Session, category: CategoryUpdate, category_code: str) -> CategoryTable:
    """update the category by ID where current_flag = 1"""
    cat = db.query(CategoryTable).filter(CategoryTable.current_flag == "1", CategoryTable.category_code == category_code).first()
    if cat is None:
        raise Exception("Category not found")
    cat.effective_to = datetime.now()
    cat.current_flag = "0"
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(cat)
    c = CategoryIn(**cat.__dict__)
    c.category_name = category.category_name
    # c.category_key = cat.category_key
    c.category_class = category.category_class if category.category_class else c.category_class
    c.effective_from = c.effective_to
    c.effective_to = None
    c.current_flag = "1"
    c_tab = CategoryTable(**c.dict())
    c_tab.category_key = cat.category_key
    db.add(c_tab)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(c_tab)
    return c_tab
```

any thoughts?

Comment: primary key must be unique(its a rule), in this case you need to filter everything are belong to your specific row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, you can import the update function from sqlalchemy if you have an update that is more complicated  than just using the primary key

```
    stmt = update(CategoryTable).where(CategoryTable.category_key == cat.category_key,
    CategoryTable.current_flag == '1', CategoryTable.effective_from == cat.effective_from).values(
        effective_to=effective_date, current_flag='0').execution_options(synchronize_session="fetch")
    db.execute(stmt)
```